# Select a row of a Table for second time

Tags: java, swing

i currently able to select a row of table using ListSelectionModel object and open a new window. but if i close that window and click that row again, it would not open anymore until i select another row of table (i can't select a row for a second time). do you know how can i solve this issue ?

this is what i have done:

```
ListSelectionModel model = table.getSelectionModel();
model.addListSelectionListener(new ListSelectionListener(){

        public void valueChanged(ListSelectionEvent e)
        {
            if(!model.getValueIsAdjusting())
            {
                int row = model.getMinSelectionIndex();
                //new Window opens :
                SubjectDetail sd = new SubjectDetail(Datalist2.project.listOfData().get(row));
            }
        }
    });
```

Comment: Since the selection doesn't change there won't be any `ListSelectionEvent` (from the list's point of view nothing happend). Thus you'd probably need to listen for clicks on the list/row.

Answer (score 2):

The selection is not working because that particular row is already selected.
Try clearing the selection when a new window is opened.
table.getSelectionModel().clearSelection().

Comment: thanks, it worked, but after clearSelection(), the row would looks like this: http://puu.sh/mVpcg/f7b8ddd678.png  how can i clear Selection for all of those columns for that row ?

Comment: `how can i clear Selection for all of those columns for that row` - try adding a table.repaint() after clearing the selection model.

Comment: unfortunately, after using getSelectionModel().clearSelection() it gives me an error of "Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: -1"